# Google Drive API - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: google-drive-api

As of 7pm Eastern on 7/6/2017 all of my requests to the Google Drive API are returning 502 Bad Gateway error.  I even tried using Google API's Explorer in the browser and am getting the same error.

Here's an example:

Request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response:

```
502

content-length:  1613
content-type:  text/html; charset=UTF-8
date:  Thu, 06 Jul 2017 23:02:40 GMT

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, 
width=device-width">
  <title>Error 502 (Server Error)!!1</title>
  <style>
    ...
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>502.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Are others experiencing this problem?

Comment: I also noticed this problem. We just have to make sure our apps are properly handling these errors :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a widespread Google OAuth outage yesterday. Most Google service were affected.

https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en-GB&v=status

Answer (score 0):

I guess it was just an intermittent problem.  It's fixed now.